# EXM 3.2.0: Email Campaign Manager doesn't show the history of drafts / created messages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

We need to setup EXM 3.2 with Sitecore 8.1 in production after we successfully configured EXM in development. Everything works fine in dev ... but in production we don't see the message history section (screenshots below)

MongoDb and the EXM.Dispatch database exist and nothing wierd apears in the logs. Any clue what might be the cause here? Thank you in advance

[image: EXM Messages in Manager Root]
[image]

Comment: Any error in front-end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore EXM Messages are stored in **`sitecore_master_index`**. Try to rebuild the index from Control Panel -> Indexing Manager.

Comment: Thanks Dylevich, this was the issue. The CD had sharded index for sitecore_master_index so this index did not exist. It turned out the  Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config  had a reference to sitecore_master_index. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have non-default location of ExM root item. Please double check that it is configured correctly: go to "/sitecore/system/Modules/E-mail Campaign Manager" and check "Default Root Parent". It should be "Austria" in your case.